# Can anyone tell me the regular expression for this object's "xauthtoken"?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
<form method="post" action="./ServiceUserHomePage.aspx?UserId=432795&amp;Username=int_jasimp&amp;SessionKey=E29A0DE7-3048-4C29-93B2-08B5FFF8EF23&amp;xauthtoken=eYa9GR3ghZGwIG46vPsyUhs61ZhT9dxrZLyYTZroSFOaaTo0KKP2yYbQbQomkbGzSFHJ8guzRF+45S%2fxgWdpDrR9zo+0DN0NZAGn1Jq91zUAj8s4UAi3JwfhMP5SKQsyPZR5FRZ7nw2eErO1+6nKDIFf%2f7Phlk2fRxJUPdg+2Tt2lusyZQBpBjMo8MxzhnOd&amp;xauthsrc=UserManagement&amp;xauthdes=EventManagementSystem" id="Form2" autocomplete="off">
```

The `xauthtoken` value should be like this:

```
xauthtoken=eYa9GR3ghZGwIG46vPsyUhs61ZhT9dxrZLyYTZroSFOaaTo0KKP2yYbQbQomkbGzSFHJ8guzRF+45S%2fxgWdpDrR9zo+0DN0NZAGn1Jq91zUAj8s4UAi3JwfhMP5SKQsyPZR5FRZ7nw2eErO1+6nKDIFf%2f7Phlk2fRxJUPdg+2Tt2lusyZQBpBjMo8MxzhnOd
```

My regular expression is:

```
xauthtoken.*?&
```

...which results in this:

```
xauthtoken=eYa9GR3ghZGwIG46vPsyUhs61ZhT9dxrZLyYTZroSFOaaTo0KKP2yYbQbQomkbGzSFHJ8guzRF+45S%2fxgWdpDrR9zo+0DN0NZAGn1Jq91zUAj8s4UAi3JwfhMP5SKQsyPZR5FRZ7nw2eErO1+6nKDIFf%2f7Phlk2fRxJUPdg+2Tt2lusyZQBpBjMo8MxzhnOd&
```

If you exclude the `&` sign, the string ends with `Od`.

Comment: What is the complete string?

Comment: Use `xauthtoken[^&]*`

Comment: Complete string <form method="post" action="./ServiceUserHomePage.aspx?UserId=432795&amp;Username=int_jasimp&amp;SessionKey=E29A0DE7-3048-4C29-93B2-08B5FFF8EF23&amp;xauthtoken=eYa9GR3ghZGwIG46vPsyUhs61ZhT9dxrZLyYTZroSFOaaTo0KKP2yYbQbQomkbGzSFHJ8guzRF+45S%2fxgWdpDrR9zo+0DN0NZAGn1Jq91zUAj8s4UAi3JwfhMP5SKQsyPZR5FRZ7nw2eErO1+6nKDIFf%2f7Phlk2fRxJUPdg+2Tt2lusyZQBpBjMo8MxzhnOd&amp;xauthsrc=UserManagement&amp;xauthdes=EventManagementSystem" id="Form2" autocomplete="off">

Comment: @jacefarm I approved your edit. I'd like to point out that things like "Regards" (and "Hello", "Thanks in advance", etc) should also be removed when editing.

Answer (score 1):

The `xauthtoken.*?&` regex pattern matches `xauthtoken` and then any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first `&` and the `&` itself.

To avoid matching the `&` but grab all chars before it, you need to use a *negated character class* `[^&]`:

```
xauthtoken[^&]*
```

Or with `=` after the `xauthtoken`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fSEx2V/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xauthtoken.*?(?=&)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GM3ID6/1